# How to change all the elements but the first one in the array to only present the difference

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, regex, function

I have multiple arrays that look more or less like so :

```js
let r = [
'Upon causing an Overloaded, Melt, Burning, Vaporize, or a Pyro-infused Swirl reaction, increases Base ATK by 20% for 12s.',
'Upon causing an Overloaded, Melt, Burning, Vaporize, or a Pyro-infused Swirl reaction, increases Base ATK by 25% for 12s.',
'Upon causing an Overloaded, Melt, Burning, Vaporize, or a Pyro-infused Swirl reaction, increases Base ATK by 30% for 12s.',
'Upon causing an Overloaded, Melt, Burning, Vaporize, or a Pyro-infused Swirl reaction, increases Base ATK by 35% for 12s.',
'Upon causing an Overloaded, Melt, Burning, Vaporize, or a Pyro-infused Swirl reaction, increases Base ATK by 40% for 12s.'
]
```

```js
let r1 = [
'Increases Movement SPD by 10%. When in battle, gain an 8% Elemental DMG Bonus every 4s. Max 4 stacks. Lasts until the character falls or leaves combat.',
'Increases Movement SPD by 10%. When in battle, earn an 8% Elemental DMG Bonus every 4s. Max 4 stacks. Lasts until the character falls or leaves combat.',
'Increases Movement SPD by 10%. When in battle, earn a 10% Elemental DMG Bonus every 4s. Max 4 stacks. Lasts until the character falls or leaves combat.',
'Increases Movement SPD by 10%. When in battle, earn a 12% Elemental DMG Bonus every 4s. Max 4 stacks. Lasts until the character falls or leaves combat.',
'Increases Movement SPD by 10%. When in battle, earn a 14% Elemental DMG Bonus every 4s. Max 4 stacks. Lasts until the character falls or leaves combat.'
]
```

The problem is that I want other elements in the array (not including the first one) to only include the word different compared to the others.

```
// <number>% //
```

In clear, I want that all the next lines will have everything replaced with `//` except the words that change. In the end I would like a result like so :

```js
[
'Upon causing an Overloaded, Melt, Burning, Vaporize, or a Pyro-infused Swirl reaction, increases Base ATK by 20% for 12s.',
'// 20% //',
'// 30% //',
'// 35% //',
'// 40% //'
]
```

I have absolutely no idea on how to accomplish this and I would like help on creating a function so when I give an array like that as input, the result above get returned.

Comment: To factor text like that would be a real chore given the different levels differences that may exist between lines.  Difference engines usually focus on 2 lines at a time. If these elements were considered regex strings, it is possible to factor out text before and after text when joined via an alternation: `element1|element2|...` leaving a single line regex to match all the elements. To reconstruct elements would require converting the common regex part `(?:[23][05]|40)` into things that could match.

Comment: The resulting regex I auto generated is this `Upon causing an Overloaded, Melt, Burning, Vaporize, or a Pyro-infused Swirl reaction, increases Base ATK by (?:[23][05]|40)% for 12s` Generating and using a scheme like this is extremely complex ! Its hard to imagine you would get a general solution to this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following function:

```
function replaceStatic(array, replacement) {
    let currSentence = array[0]; // First comparison sentence
    let splittedCurrSentence = currSentence.split(" "); // Get currSentence words in an array (for further comparison)
    const newArray = [currSentence]; // The array to return. First sentence can already be in there
    for (let s = 1, len = array.length; s < len; s++) { // Loop from second to last sentence
        const sentence = array[s]; // Current sentence to analyse
        const splittedSentence = sentence.split(" "); // Words array for the sentence to analyze
        let replace = true; // Set a boolean to handle when you need to replace the current word
        const mappedSplittedSentence = splittedSentence.map(word => {
            // Maps every words with itself (if new), the replacement string (if not new a last word was new) or doesn't map
            if (!splittedCurrSentence.includes(word)) {
                replace = true;
                return word;
            } else if (replace) {
                replace = false; // Set to false so if next word is also new, there won't be consecutive replacements
                return replacement;
            }
        }).filter(word => word !== undefined); // Remove unmapped words (consecutive already existing words)
        newArray.push(mappedSplittedSentence.join(" ")); // Stringify the mapped sentence
        // Set comparison sentence to the current sentence for next iteration
        // This is done so every check is made compared to previous sentence
        // You can comment/remove this if you only want to compare to the first sentence
        splittedCurrSentence = splittedSentence;
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

If you call your r array it returns:

```
console.log( replaceStatic(r, "//") );
/*
Output:
[
  'Upon causing an Overloaded, Melt, Burning, Vaporize, or a Pyro-infused Swirl reaction, increases Base ATK by 20% for 12s.',
  '// 25% //',
  '// 30% //',
  '// 35% //',
  '// 40% //'
]
*/
```

With r1 it gives:

```
console.log( replaceStatic(r1, "//") );
/*
Output:
[
  'Increases Movement SPD by 10%. When in battle, gain an 8% Elemental DMG Bonus every 4s. Max 4 stacks. Lasts until the character falls or leaves combat.',
  '// earn //',
  '// a 10% //',
  '// 12% //',
  '// 14% //'
]
*/
```

There are probably better solutions but this should be general enough to fit your case.

Answer (score -1):

I would start with a "template string" (just a name, not realted template literals) that has a specific phrase to be replaced, and an array of the values to replace it with, then map the replacement values with the template string.

```js
const templateString = "Upon causing an Overloaded, Melt, Burning, Vaporize, or a Pyro-infused Swirl reaction, increases Base ATK by **percent**% for 12s.";
const percentages = [20,25,30,40];
const replacedStrings = percentages.map(
  function(p) {
    return templateString.replace("**percent**",p);
  }
);
console.log("replacedStrings",replacedStrings);
```

Comment: I don't want to only remove text from the arrays with this text specifically, I have alot of arrays that have the same principle so I can't just have a text to be replaced :/

Comment: Can you give a better example? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "I don't have enough space." How many arrays are we talking about?

Comment: I have about 14 arrays~ and they all look like the array I gave in the question, they give some "special power" and the only thing that is different in each element in the array is a number, and I want the second, third etc.. elements to look like `// <new number different from the other ones>% //`

Comment: If that's the case, I don't understand why my solution doesn't work for you. It's creating a new array with the original text and specified percentage.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know the porcentage at all and idk how to get it

Comment: That doesn't seem like a javascript question or anything SO can help with. What do these percentages represent?  We can't tell you where to get your data.